# Symmetric bilinear form from Hessian

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, tensors, bilinear-form, hessian-matrix

Assuming a PDE is given by the Hesse-operator
$$ 
-\nabla \otimes \nabla \lambda = \mathbf{F} \, ,
$$
then testing the left-hand-side with a symmetric tensor $\mathbf{S}$ leads to
$$
-\langle \mathbf{S}, \nabla \otimes \nabla \lambda \rangle = \langle \mathrm{div} \, \mathbf{S}, \nabla \lambda \rangle \, , 
$$
(ignoring boundary terms) which is a non-symmetric bilinear form.

(1) Is there a way to (in general) derive a symmetric bilinear form from the Hesse-operator?

If (1) is not possible; then assuming we know the following relations for the field
$$
\lambda = \mathrm{tr} \, \mathbf{T} \, , \qquad \mathbf{T}=\mathbf{T}^T \,, \qquad \mathrm{div \, div} \,\mathbf{T} = \Delta \mathrm{tr} \, \mathbf{T} \, , 
$$
(2) is it reasonable to assume that the test function $\mathbf{S}$ implies the same relations such that
$$
\langle \mathrm{div} \, \mathbf{S}, \nabla \lambda \rangle = -\langle \mathrm{div \, div} \, \mathbf{S}, \mathrm{tr} \, \mathbf{T} \rangle = -\langle \Delta \mathrm{tr} \, \mathbf{S}, \mathrm{tr} \, \mathbf{T} \rangle = \langle \nabla \mathrm{tr} \, \mathbf{S}, \nabla \mathrm{tr} \, \mathbf{T} \rangle \, ,
$$
(again, neglecting boundary terms) which is a symmetric bilinear form with respect to $\{ \mathbf{S}, \mathbf{T} \}$ ?